# How to develope multi language OpenERP module in OpenERP 7?

Tags: openerp-7

I want to develop a module that should support two languages
How to make `OpenERP` multi language

1-English
2-Dari

with links to change the language from one to another

I am new to `OpenERP` development please help me with practical sample codes and explanation.

Answer (score 1):

First of all if the second language you want to support in your module isn't already loaded to OpenERP you have to load it. 
To do so, you have to go to "translations" -> "load a translation" in the settings menu, and load your second language.

Then in your module code, do the following import in your py files:

```
from openerp.tools.translate import _
```

Then continue developing you're module... When you're done developing you can start translate it!

**First, export the po file.**
To export the po file, go to "translations" -> "Import/Export" -> "Export translation" under the "Settings" menu. Choose the language you want to translate to, the format of the file to translate (you should select "PO") and the name(s) of the module(s) you want to translate.

Click the "download po file" and save it to your computer. Keep all the "msgid" strings as they are (**better, don't touch anything but the "msgstr" entries!**) and translate all "msgstr" to your language.

You're almost done!

In your module, create a folder named "**i18n**" and put there the po file you just edited. Upload the folder with the PO file in it to your server, and update your module. You're module should now be translated and displayed in the new language to users who have that language selected in their profile.

Hope this helped!